# How limit works in mongodb internally

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am working on mongodb and wondering how the limit(int) works internally.
I actually want to optimize a call for query, depending on volume.

Is it just like limit in RDBS like oracle. If no then what is execution plan?
I even dont knonw if mongo works on the basis executions plans.

the only information I can find about this is:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/

Comment: To view details about how mongo will run your query, append `.explain()` to it. For example: http://pastie.org/10771077

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It has a lot of information but the what I need is the the execution of limit. Like I get a regular expression/ machine diagram for rdbms , the result with explain days "stage" : "LIMIT", 
            "limitAmount" : NumberInt(2) which is insufficient for understanding, I don't know mongo much.

Comment: It is like an RDBS it will just go to that point and stop. This can help query performance as you think it could